# Reading Data from .txt file in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a query in which I'm looking up data for 90k+ IDs. When I normally have a list of IDs to query data for, I'll use the SQL list syntax:

```
where id in (1,2,3...,n)
```

However, 90K IDs is a little overwhelming to have in a query. So I thought it may be a little easier to read this list of IDs from a text file, bulk insert the IDs into a temporary table, and perform a sub-select in the where clause.

```
create table #temp1

bulk insert #temp1 from 'C:\Users\BXS8145\Documents\Temp\file.txt'

select * from mainTable where id in (select id from #temp1)
```

I am unable to do this however, as I don't have the appropriate permissions to use bulk insert.

Is there any alternative?

Comment: Where are the ids coming from?  another table, query, server?

Comment: @Matt They're given to me in an excel file, and in most cases generated from a previous query - however let's say for the sake of argument that I have no way to obtain this original query.

Comment: You can try `openrowset` function to read from .txt file. See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190312.aspx

Comment: Not certain how often you do this but my first reaction would be a python or powershell script. Reading from text files and database are fairly trivial in Python and you have the added bonus that you can use the same script to easily output your results. Also, you could break the reads into more manageable chunks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try `OPENROWSET` instead of `bulkinsert`.

```
SELECT * into temptable
FROM OPENROWSET('Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0',
                'Excel 8.0;Database=C:\Documents and Settings\....\example.xls;IMEX=1',
                'SELECT * FROM [Sheet1$]')
```

Other Options

`SSIS package to import Excel file`

You can also generate a package like this from SSMS on the fly by right clicking on database going to tasks then import date and setup excel as source file.

Do you have permission to create a linked server?

If you have them in Excel or I supposed even the txt file you can also create a linked server.  you will have to open SSMS as administrator to do this!  Also the file will have to be an accessible path for I believe both yourself and your sqlagnet.  E.g. local path or a file share. Once you open SSMS create the Excel Linked Server then query.

Here is one tool I use to generate teh linked server statement and add it:

```
/* !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

    IN ORDER TO QUERY EXCEL YOU MUST RUN SSMS AS ADMINISTRATOR!!!!!!!

    This doesn't seem to affect import jobs run under the SQL Agent, but the way SSMS handles
    permissions to folders it is not prviledged when accessing the ACE 12.0 OLEDB provider.
    I have tried all of the in-process and giving direct permissions, etc. and only running SSMS as
    Administrator seems to work
*/

    DECLARE @RC int
    DECLARE @server nvarchar(128)
    DECLARE @srvproduct nvarchar(128)
    DECLARE @provider nvarchar(128)
    DECLARE @datasrc nvarchar(4000)
    DECLARE @location nvarchar(4000)
    DECLARE @provstr nvarchar(4000)
    DECLARE @catalog nvarchar(128)
    -- Set parameter values
    SET @server = N'XLSERVER'
    SET @srvproduct = N'Excel'
    SET @provider = N'Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0'
    --SET @provider = N'Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.15.0'
    SET @datasrc = N'FULLFILEPATH'
    --SET @provstr = N'Excel 12.0; HDR=Yes' ---wihtout imex
    SET @provstr = N'Excel 12.0;IMEX=1;HDR=YES;' ----Office 2007+
    --SET @provstr = N'Excel 8.0;IMEX=1;HDR=YES;' ----Office 97-2003 Uses Jet 4.0 instead of ACE 12.0

    IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM sys.servers WHERE name = @server)
    BEGIN
        --Drop The Current Server
        EXEC master.dbo.sp_dropserver @server, @droplogins='droplogins'
    END

    EXEC @RC = [master].[dbo].[sp_addlinkedserver] @server, @srvproduct, @provider, 
    @datasrc, @location, @provstr, @catalog
```

And here is how you can select from the data once you have created the linked server. Note the file cannot be open!

```
SELECT *
FROM
    XLSERVER...Sheet1$
```